# Refresh index mapping and reduce number of total fields

Tags: node.js, elasticsearch

In my current application I have setup a search for my (web-)shop items. Until now I have always worked with dynamic mappings and now encountered the problem, that I have reached the default index.total_fields.limit of 1000.

Now what I want to do is to reduce the number the total number of fields (reduce the mappings total_fields) just by putting a new mapping where I set dynamic to false on most of the unnecessary properties.

Somehow when doing this, I now only can't reduce the number of total fields, I also get the 1000 total fields limit error while putting the new mapping to the items index. Is there a way to refresh the mapping on an existing index without the need to recreate a new index with correct mappings.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, the mapping is only applied when creating an index, if you want to change the mapping of any field you will need to create a new index or reindex your current index into a newly created index with the correct mapping.

Alternatively you can increase the limit of total mapping fields, but having too many fields can impact in performance.

```
PUT your_index/_settings
{
  "index.mapping.total_fields.limit": 5000
}
```

Comment: Yeah, It looks like that there is currently no alternative besides recreating the index. Thanks.